# is it possible to include css in php

Tags: php, css

I am trying to display an image obtained from php code. Below is my code n=but it is not displaying anything. Someone please help.

```
<?php

$db_conx=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","sultan","slide");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM photo WHERE username='shail' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
// Fetch the user row from the query above
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $profile_id = $row["id"];
    $avatar1 = $row["avatar1"];

}
$profile_pic1 = '<img src="user/shail/'.$avatar1.'" width="100" height="80" >';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
#small{ background-image:<?php echo $profile_pic1 ?>;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="small"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks
Shail

Comment: shouldn't it be like: `:url('path/to/heaven etc.')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using image tag on backgrount image. you just need to give exact image path only.

```
$img_path = ''; // your image path
<style>
#small{ background-image:url("<?php echo $img_path ?>");}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use wrong syntax for your background image so it won't display.

You should use for example:

```
#small{ background-image: url('yourimagename.jpg');}
```

and you set your `$profile_pic1` img tag.

You should change your code:

```
 $profile_pic1 = '<img src="user/shail/'.$avatar1.'" width="100" height="80" >';
```

into:

```
$profile_pic1 = 'user/shail/'.$avatar1;
```

and your code:

```
#small{ background-image:<?php echo $profile_pic1 ?>;}
```

into:

```
#small{ background-image: url('<?php echo $profile_pic1 ?>'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to add whole  img tag to the css , Just pass image there ,

```
 $image=  'user/shail/'.$avatar1; //Image

 #small{ background-image:url('<?php echo $image?>' }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did almost makes sense, however your `$profile_pic1` is set as a HTML tag whereas you need to write it according to the CSS syntax, provided you continue writing it inside a style tag.

[CSS Background - W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)